# Innsbruck ClaimCenter - ExitPoint opening in a new window vs new tab in Flaine

Tags: guidewire

Noticed that the Exit Point urls were opening a new tab in Flaine. After upgrading to Innsbruck, they are opening a new window. The PCF files were same, and no changes were made. Not found much information in the documentation.

Trying to find what kind of settings can change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This change was included in the Garmisch (aka 2023.06)release.  I don't have information on why it changed other than it was changed to fix some other issues.  If this is an issue with your usage of the application please open a case with Guidewire support in order to get advice on possible workarounds.

More generally, part of this change was to use the browsers native "new window" behavior instead of forcing something different on the server side.  Different browsers can have different behavior for this action.